# error handling datetime.datetime.strptime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have got this DataFrame:

```
df_sales:          time            store       transacction      name
0                  2013-01-01      5           770               numero5

->time: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I try this, hoping to get a datetime:

```
df_sales['time']=df_sales.time.apply(lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

but I get:

```
df_sales:         time            store       transacction      name
0                 2013-01-01      5           770               numero5

->time: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Why don´t I get a datetime?
thks.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC need:

```
df_sales['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sales['time'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: @DanielGarciaDeCceresHerran - It is no problem :)